# How to use the \repchoruses command

Tags: songs

I am using the "Songs package" and want to use the \repchorus command so it produces the "slides-book" showing repeated choruses without affecting the other books like the lyrics and the chords books. Anyone used this option before and can assist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn on automatically repeating choruses, but only for slide books, you can use code like the following:

```
\ifslides\repchoruses\fi
```